# Возможно ли обратится к указателю функции из другой программы? C++

Tags: c++, linux

Есть две программы на одном компьютере. Возможно ли сделать так:

1. Программа 1 достает указатели 2 своих функций и отправляет по UNIX сокету другой программе.
2. Программа 2 получает эти указатели и с помощью сокета она передает 1 указатель на свою функцию.
3. Сокет уничтожается и программы проводят "пинг тест", обмениваясь "Hello program!" друг с другом.
4. Profit!

Возможно ли такое провернуть? Главный вопрос: как исполнить функцию по указателю и как передать ей параметры?

Comment: Только если в одном адресном пространстве будут обе программы. А исполнить не проблема - кастуете к нужному типу, и вызываете

Comment: Такое возможно делать если загрузить скомпилированный переносимый код функций в общую память (shared memory) доступную обоим программам. Но думаю что для Вас это будет непосильная задача, да и не вижу смысла в таких кульбитах. PS: два разных процесса обычно находятся в разных адресных пространствах, несовместимых друг с другом.

Comment: Во как оно просто, указатель на функцию через сокет перебросить. А пацаны, которые CORBA/SOAP/DCOM писали, и не в курсе.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @VladD, но в dos'е бы сработало? Или тоже нет?

Comment: Вам проще это реализовывать посредством RPC или IPC, т.е. организовать междупрограммное общение. Таким образом если одна программа знает о функциях другой, она сможет сделать вызов через сервис, предоставляемый другой программой, а этот сервис может быть привязан к чему угодно - сокету, порту или ещё чему.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, в ДОСе в пределах одной машины :) Там общее адресное пространство, да.

Comment: @Qwertiy более того, оно и на Win9x работало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать разделяемую память, по сути она для этого и служит, связать две программы одной памятью.
На [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/122108/) даже статейка есть

Comment: Не сработает же?

Comment: @Qwertiy почему не сработает-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, чтобы сработало, надо чтобы всё, что будет вызывать эта функция, тоже находилось в shared memory. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну это же очевидно :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но при этом нереализуемо ведь?

Comment: @Qwertiy почему?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52849/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 4):

Так сделать нельзя, так как каждое приложение имеет своё адресное пространство. Но можно организовать общую память, в которую первая программа записывает ДАННЫЕ, а вторая программа читает их и как-то обрабатывает СВОИМИ функциями, и то же самое в обратную сторону. То есть надо смотреть в сторону изменения логики программы.